# MYSQL select entries from last 24 hours

Tags: mysql, expresso-store

I've read prior entries on this, but those fixes don't seem to work. I suspect (?) it is a way that the date is stored within the database, its format I suppose. Could be wrong.

Anyway:

```
WHERE exp_store_orders.order_status_name =  
'Approved' AND exp_store_orders.order_completed_date 
> DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This is the current attempt.

order_completed_date format example: `1396891300`

This is from/for Expresso Store for ExpressionEngine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *`order_completed_date` format example: `1396891300`*

Use `FROM_UNIXTIME...` on the `order_completed_date`

```
FROM_UNIXTIME( exp_store_orders.order_completed_date )
> DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

If order date is `indexed`, to make use of it, convert the other part of the date to `unix_time` format.

**Example**

```
exp_store_orders.order_completed_date 
> UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR ) )
```

**Refer to**:

- [FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime),
- [FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

  - Format UNIX timestamp as a date
- [UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

  - Return a UNIX timestamp

Comment: wouldn't it be better to convert the other operand, so MySQL could use an index: `exp_store_orders.order_completed_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))`

Comment: It can be. And it all depends if order date is indexed or not, again. Answer updated.

Comment: Will remember, for my future answers. :)

Comment: Did this and it seems to be working flawlessly. I knew the answer was something simple relating to the format (or thereabouts). I dunno where I'd be without you guys to turn too sometimes.